# .save & .create in same async function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, mongoose-schema

Below is my code to save data in a mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const sampleschema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name:{
            type:String
        },
        age:{
            type:Number
        }
    },
    {collection :"Sample_collection"}
)
const samplemodel = mongoose.model('sample_coll',sampleschema)


const add = async () =>
{
    const samplerecord = new samplemodel({    
        name:'FFFF',
        age:26
    })
try
{   
    await  samplerecord.save()                 // Line A
await  samplemodel.create(samplerecord)    // Line B
   
    console.log("Style")
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log("This is error",e)
}
}
```

Now I have written both Line A & Line B . Now , I think two records shall be created in my database with same value except different `_id` , however I am seeing that only one record is being created. Why is it happening so ? Even if I change the order of line A and line B same issue persists. What is the issue because of which only one record is being created ?

Answer (score 0):

**await samplerecord.save();** it gives the data which is saved in database as it is promise based so, await/(then-catch) is required .

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const sampleschema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    age: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  { collection: "Sample_collection" }
);
const samplemodel = mongoose.model("sample_coll", sampleschema);

const add = async () => {
  try {
    const samplerecord = new samplemodel({
      name: "FFFF",
      age: 26,
    });

    //.save() method returns the object that it saves in database
    let result = await samplerecord.save(); // Line A
    //.create() does not need .save() method
    await samplemodel.create(result); // Line B

    console.log("Style");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("This is error", e);
  }
};
```

Comment: This will still only store one document in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The reason only one document is stored in the database is because when you create a new instance of the model here:

```
const samplerecord = new samplemodel({    
    name:'FFFF',
    age:26
});
```

mongoose actually assigns an `_id` property to  `samplerecord` before it's even saved. That means by the time you pass `samplerecord` to the `await samplemodel.create(samplerecord)` function on Line B, that `ObjectId` already exists in the database because you called the `save()` method on `samplerecord` on Line A so you can't have two with the same `_id`.